# What free and public image JSON API can I use for testing JSON request

Tags: ajax, json, api, angularjs, jsonp

I'm playing around with AngularJS and would like to use some free API's to get some images. I was looking at Flickr but you need to register a app to make use of it. I'm looking for something I can use right of the bat.

http://www.jsontest.com/ comes close but can't get any images.

Comment: https://picsum.photos/v2/list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- What about the "Standard Image Sizes" List over at http://dummyimage.com/#standards?

**Edit in 2023:**

> - http://schematic-ipsum.herokuapp.com/ has a nice `lipsum` extension that generates images from http://hhhhold.com/

These ones are down.

Answer (score 9):

you can find a big library of photos, posts, album, comments and a lot of things in

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can find some of them in the JSON REST API Resources.

**https://github.com/zazk/Open-Api-Resources**

Examples with no token/authentification. Some links has images.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but have you tried using https://api.imgur.com/ ?

Comment: Looked at it but you need to register an app. Just want something I can start using right away.

Comment: My advice would be to just register. You will waste too much time on finding an API. Good luck!

Comment: I can't because the require a callback url and the app is just a local app

Comment: What about [Picasa](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/) ?

Comment: Seems like it has no JSON interface.

Comment: you can use this free api, no need to register https://picsum.photos/v2/list